# StackOverFriends! - Compare your results with your Twitter/Facebook friends!

Tags: app, facebook, twitter

### Screenshot

[image: StackOverFriends! screenshot]

### About

StackOverFriends! lets you log with your Stack account and link your Twitter and Facebook account to look for friends that you have on StackExchange!
(your friends have to be on the app, so spread the word and let them know about it!)

I'm developing also the Android app for the app, so stay tuned!

Let me know what you think, if something goes wrong post it here or send me an email. :)

(JonSkeet on StackOverflow was added manually for testing porpouse! To test the app so just [follow him](https://twitter.com/jonskeet), or [follow me](https://twitter.com/enrichmann)!)

#### License

StackOverFriends! is actually closed source because of his development state (it's full of garbage), but I'm thinking about opening it.

#### Link

http://stackoverfriends.appspot.com/

#### Platform

I've tested it on Firefox bbut should work on all major browsers.

### Contact

Author: [Enrico Candino](https://stackexchange.com/users/451752/enrichman)
Website: [enricocandino.it/](http://enricocandino.it/)
[Twitter](https://twitter.com/enrichmann) - [Google+](https://plus.google.com/104624518617408670696)

### Code

Build in Java on the server side, Bootstrap for the front-end.

Comment: I don't work for me, It don't show https://twitter.com/H2CO3_iOS that have account on SO and when I follow you it show myself.

Comment: I've followed you and I can see our rank. Remember that to show the progress of the user they have to be on the system, so H2CO3_iOS should log into the app to link his account. Can you tell him to log and see if it's working? :)

Comment: Oh I see, so you can only see users that are regestered in an app.

Comment: Yes, because I need to map the user on Stack with his Twitter/Facebook ID. :)

Comment: @ Enrichman can't you match on stuff like real name or website?